# Android - Custom ListView disable scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview, scroll, touch-event

I have a custom ListView which checks for a value in its adapter, and if its false it should disable scrolling.  The reason I need to do this is because inside the listview are rows of horizontal listviews (using this implementation: https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android) and if you scroll slightly up or down whilst scrolling on of these horizontal views, they stop scrolling and the listview instead scrolls.

The issue with this code is that it doesn't always seem to prevent the listview from scrolling, and it also doesn't pass the action through to the child (horizontal listview) like I believe it should (passing false).

Does anyone have any idea how I can get it to stop scrolling and still pass the movement action through to the child?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: it seems ALMOST IMPOSSIBLE to solve this problem.  it sucks!